# Python Simple_Salesforce Close Connection

Tags: python, rest, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I just recently started using the Simple_Saleforce package for python
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-salesforce

I am wondering how long does the connection last once you have logged in? Is there a manual way to close() the connection? I have looked through the documentation and source code, but perhaps I missed this little detail.

As context, I am building a celery task to poll salesforce every few minutes and was wondering do I need to reopen a connection (i.e. login) every time I poll, or if the global login will suffice (for how long)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the SalesFOrce REST API that is used by simple-salesforce library:

> Access tokens have a limited lifetime specified by the session timeout
>   in Salesforce. If an application uses an expired access token, a
>   “Session expired or invalid” error is returned. If the application is
>   using the Web server or user-agent OAuth authentication flows, a
>   refresh token may be provided during authorization that can be used to
>   get a new access token.

So yes, there is a timeout for your session, and from the documentation you can set it up on your SalesForce:

> The session timeout for an access token can be configured in
>   Salesforce from Setup by clicking Security Controls | Session
>   Settings.

So yes you have to request a new session ID once your session timed out. And if you want to close the connection manually you can destroy the session by setting its age: session.setMaxAge(-1).

Link to the [full documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm)

Hope this help, Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was helpful. I understand how the session.setMaxAge(-1) works. However, is there a way do to this through simple_salesforce? I looked through the source code, and cannot find any object that may have set session and the setMaxAge function.

Comment: I did not see the code for the simple salesforce library, but if you did and did not find any, i guess you are better writing your own code using the request library for example and implementing what you want. Request is quit good and supports OAuth 2.0 too!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to re-establish my simple-salesforce connection by passing the `instance_id` and `session_id` back to the `Salesforce` class in a try/except block.

```py
from simple-salesforce import Salesforce
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

# Original authentication
sf = Salesforce(username='YOUR_USERNAME', 
                password='YOUR_PASSWORD', 
                security_token='YOUR_SECURITY_TOKEN')

# Some amount of time passes causing Salesforce to close the connection...

try:
    # Attempt your request here...
    record = sf.Account.get('ACCOUNT_ID')
except ConnectionError:
    # This line will re-establish the connection
    sf = Salesforce(instance=sf.sf_instance, session_id=sf.session_id)
    # Attempt your request again here...
    record = sf.Account.get('ACCOUNT_ID')
```